# Tortoisegit: How to fetch from a new remote branch?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am working with tortoisegit and have a local repository where i have configured a remote repository for fetching and pushing the code.

Now i add a new branch to the remote repository. Then, from my local repository, i execute a "fetch" from the remote repository. The expectation is that the new branch is fetched and can then be merged.

But instead the branch is ignored by Tortoisegit.
I'm trying it via Windows Explorer > Right click > TortoiseGit > Fetch. There i cannot select the new branch, so when i execute the fetch, the new branch is not fetched. The new branch is not tracked.

How can i get Tortoisegit to recognize new remote branches? I can only add and remove remotes in the settings, but i cannot configure ref-specs?

Comment: In which dialog are you trying to do the fetch? Is the remote branch a tracked branch?

Comment: My guess is that you expect to have a new branch created which has the same name as your remote branch. The result of the fetch will be in remote/branchname

Comment: I do not expect to have a new local branch created. I expect that i see a new remote ref after i perform a fetch. This doesn't happen.

Comment: @nemoo I've been using TortoiseGit for many many years and have never seen this but right now i've got a repo that has many branches but no matter what I do I cannot set origin and download all branches; I'm only getting develop. Bizarre... what did you do? FWIW after I hit send I'm going to check out a new clone... but still. Weird...

Comment: FWIW2 ...new repo/clone worked. Turn it off turn it on again :)

Answer (score 8):

Suppose your remote is set to 'origin'. Now, when you execute git fetch, all the branches under 'origin' are fetched to your local.
To fetch a branch,  no need to select that specific branch.

Answer (score 0):

I already had a similar problem, maybe that's because I cloned a repo a specific branch with depth 1, so no other branches were referenced in the local repository history.
Solution was to re-clone the repo without depth 1 option.

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to switch to the new branch as I did. To do that, via Windows Explorer > Right click > TortoiseGit > Switch/Checkout. Then select branch for "Switch To", make sure Option are correctly selected accordingly, such as "Create New Branch", "Overwrite working tree changes(force), and/or other applicable options. With these I was able to switch to the new branch that I couldn't through Git Sync window.